# Line break in react text area being treated as space wrongly and can be removed with trim()

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a text area like below which I try to remove the leading and trailing spaces of the string but I want to include the number of new line charactor in the string.

```
const [textValue, setTextValue] = useState('')

const onChangeValue= ({target: {value}}) => {
    console.log(value.length);
    console.log(value.trim().length);
    console.log(value.replace(/^\s+|\s+$/g, '').length);
    setTextValue(value);
};

<textarea
     onChange={onChangeValue}
     noAutoResize
     width={'100%'}
     height={'15em'}
     value={textValue}
     maxLength={maxLength}
/>
```

If I keep pressing the enter button on the textArea to add line breaks, the `value.length` keep increasing but `value.trim().length` always remains in 0.

According to https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim, the trim() method removes **whitespace** only

Why it it also remove my line break? Even using regex it has the same behavior. it seems the state is storing a space instead.

Is there any way to achieve such requirement?

Comment: Yes I mean the classic `textarea`, nice catch thankyou

Comment: `.trim()` and `.replace()` don't change the original string

Comment: YeXiaoRain value after trim() is supposed to be increased if I just press enter because new charactor being added are not spaces, but new line charactor

Comment: you just want a function remove `non-line terminators`? check the doc again, it says 'trim()', `A new string representing str stripped of whitespace from both its beginning and end. Whitespace is defined as white space characters plus line terminators.` , you need implement a custom function. which not remove `line terminators`

Comment: oh wow @YeXiaoRain good catch...do you have any solution to exclude line terminators?

Comment: use reaplce+regex, don't use `\s`, use something like `[\t\f\v ]` instead, and put what you want else inside.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whitespace is defined as white space characters plus line terminators

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/Trim

your case should use regexp:

```js
function trimSpace(str) {
  return str.replace(/^[ \t]+|[ \t]+$/g, '')
}
```

and call

```js
const onChangeValue= ({target: {value}}) => {
    console.log(value.length);
    console.log(trimSpace(value));
    setTextValue(value);
};
```

Comment: I did this exactly the same but it has the same behavior of using trim().

Comment: my mistake i fixed the answer try again

Comment: Note that this will not support Japanese white character styles

Comment: the edited solution work as expected for me